# p-tags from RTE field getting stripped - but only after the first entry

Tags: templates

So this is strange. Template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="[channel_name]"}

    {rich_text_field}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

For the first entry, the text in the field will return wrapped with p tags. For the rest of the entries, all p tags are missing.

If I switch the field to a normal textarea instead, p-tags will be returned as excpected, for all entries.

I can find no errors anywhere in any logs, and template debugging returns nothing unusual.

The text renders correctly with p tags within the 'view code' part of RTE inside the control panel.

Oh, and this is the newest, 2.6.1 version of EE.

Any pointers where I can start looking for errors?

EDIT (more info):
So the problem seems to be that the string ($this->text_format), during parsing, isn't marked as 'xhtml', but rather as 'none', and therefore isn't passed through to the auto_typography() method (I think it's somewhere in EE_typography.php, but I can't remember exactly). Again, this is *only* for the subsequent entries, and not the first.

Comment: If you add offset="1" (to remove the first entry returned) or if you change the sort order, is the result the same - first one has p tags and the others don't?

Comment: I haven't tried the offset, but reordering give same result - still the first entry in the loop that's correct.

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I'm seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hacked core in order to fix this bug:

In system/expressionengine/modules/rte/ft.rte.php, find:

```
        array(
            'html_format'   => $this->row['channel_html_formatting'],
            'auto_links'    => $this->row['channel_auto_link_urls'],
            'allow_img_url' => $this->row['channel_allow_img_urls']
        )
```

Add this line in the array:

```
            'text_format'   => $this->row['field_ft_'.$this->field_id],
```

Feel free to report this bug with a link to this page.

---

Slightly related: I've also hacked this same method in order to avoid extra new lines to create empty `<p>` tags.

I changed:

```
ee()->functions->encode_ee_tags(ee()->typography->parse_file_paths($data))
```

to

```
ee()->functions->encode_ee_tags(trim(ee()->typography->parse_file_paths($data)))
```

Comment: This worked. Ellislab suggested the solution below, but this seems like a better solution as it queries the database for the proper text format.

Also, thanks for the bonus solution to the extra newline problem, been looking for a way to fix that!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a suggested bugfix [here](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19405).

It's also discussed [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/235328/) on Ellislab's support site.

Basically find this code (line 80 in system/expressionengine/modules/rte/ft.rte.php):

```
array(
    'html_format' => $this->row['channel_html_formatting'],
```

And replace with:

```
array(
    'text_format' => 'xhtml',
    'html_format' => $this->row['channel_html_formatting'],
```

I can confirm I had the same problem and this fixed it.